# Google analytics session-level custom variable not showing all visits

Tags: session, variables, google-analytics

I'm having trouble tracking info through GA Custom Variables. I'm using for the same kind of pages both a page-level and a session-level Custom Variable, both in different slots. As I understand from documentation, since I'm doing it in different Slots, there shouldn't be any problem, but my session-level Custom Variable is showing much less visits than before the page-level one was added. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2531061-1']);



_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
           2,           // Slot
           'Profile Type',          // Variable name
           'With Stream - External Player',             // Variable value
           2                // Scope.
]);




_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
           1,           // Slot
           'Test - Improve Bounce Rate',            // Variable name
           'Control',               // Variable value
           3                // Scope.
]);

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

Any clues on what could be wrong?

Thanks!

JC

Comment: Code looks correct. Have you tried removing the page-level Custom variable (on slot 1) to see if this is really correlated to your drop in the Visits with session level ?

Comment: I assume you're seeing this in a custom report? Tell us how the report is set up (which metrics/dimensions).

Comment: any update ? Which custom report dimension/metrics do you use ?

Comment: what kind of website is it? what is the exact purpose? by the way, trackPageLoadTime has been deprecated. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration it's now default with the script.